# Erase cache web view during install apk

Tags: android, caching, webview, apk

I developp a apk android with a web view (app not publish in app store google)
and for the new versions, i would like  erase the web view cache google chrome
during the apk installation .

Is is possible ?
If not, what the best way? perhaps test a file version file and erase cache when web view load url ...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any idea about if it can be done while installing APK. But you can do it easily using `SharedPreference` using the following steps.

1. Store your current app version in SharedPreference.
2. Check stored app version and installed app version when the app opened.
3. Clear cache if both versions are not the same.

Comment: indeed it seems to be a good solution and in a store if not exist for the old version I store in SharedPreference